# Android Async task with different content view and swipe tabs

Tags: android, asynchronous, tabs, setcontentview

I'm using `swipe tab` menu to generate the view of the app, on start I'm apart from generating the layout for the tabs, I'm also running `async task`, which is Rss reader. At the moment I've got three tabs, the Rss feed is on first tab. The problem is when I go to third tab and back to first one, the feed disappears. I think this is because the `async task` which retrieves the Rss feed only runs in the main activity, but when I try to call this task when the first tab is being rendered I keep getting `null pointer exception` for either `text view` (if no network connection) or on `listview`, I'm not sure why that is not pointing to the correct layout, any ideas?

This is code for async task:

```
 public class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>> {

        private Activity ownerActivity;
        private Exception exceptionToBeThrown;

        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Debug the task thread name
            Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RssReader", e.getMessage());
                exceptionToBeThrown = e;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
            if (exceptionToBeThrown != null) {
                TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);
                error.setText("No internet connection");  //Null pointer expection
            } else {

                // Get a ListView from main view
                ListView listItems= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView); //Null pointer exception

                // Create a list adapter
                ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
                // Set list adapter for the ListView
                listItems.setAdapter(adapter);

                // Set list view item click listener
                listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
            }


    }
```

}

Here is code for my rss feed tab:

```
public class RssFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        new MainActivity();
        MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
        GetRSSDataTask task = ma.new GetRSSDataTask();
        task.execute("newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/world/rss.xml");

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss_news, container, false);
         return rootView;
    }
}
```

On create in main activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set reference to this activity
        local = this;
        GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();

        // Start download RSS task
        task.execute("newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/world/rss.xml");

        // Debug the thread name
        Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:** Try writing your `GetRSSDataTask` class inside `RssFragment`, and call it from `RssFragment` on `onCreateView`. The error is because you create instance of `main activity` to call `GetRSSDataTask` in `RssFragment`.

**Solution:** 
RssFragment.java:

```
public class RssFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        GetRSSDataTask task = new GetRSSDataTask();
        task.execute("newsrss.bbc.co.uk/rss/newsonline_uk_edition/world/rss.xml");

         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss_news, container, false);
         return rootView;
    }


    public class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem>> {

        private Activity ownerActivity;
        private Exception exceptionToBeThrown;

        @Override
        protected List<RssItem> doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // Debug the task thread name
            Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                // Create RSS reader
                RssReader rssReader = new RssReader(urls[0]);

                // Parse RSS, get items
                return rssReader.getItems();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("RssReader", e.getMessage());
                exceptionToBeThrown = e;
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<RssItem> result) {
            if (exceptionToBeThrown != null) {
                TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);
                error.setText("No internet connection");  //Null pointer expection
            } else {

                // Get a ListView from main view
                ListView listItems= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMainView); //Null pointer exception

                // Create a list adapter
                ArrayAdapter<RssItem> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(local, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
                // Set list adapter for the ListView
                listItems.setAdapter(adapter);

                // Set list view item click listener
                listItems.setOnItemClickListener(new ListListener(result, local));
            }


    }
}
```

MainActivity.java onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set reference to this activity
        local = this;

        // Debug the thread name
        Log.d("RssReader", Thread.currentThread().getName());

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but the 'Fragment' class is part of android library

Comment: @TheSortOfProgrammer i mean your Fragment, which is RssFragment

Comment: I tried that, but that would mean I would have to extend the class by Activity and thats not possible, as its already extending Fragment

Comment: @TheSortOfProgrammer check code again, you assume you have listview inside your fragment, not in mainActivity. Also if you get errors on passing context in your fragment, pass getActivity() when context is needed.